# No input paths specified in job

Tags: pyspark

Please help to sort this out, thank you:

I have a cluster in my work and there are three nodes with spark installed. I want to do some work using spark, on one of the node, I have data file in my directory, when I create a dataframe, it seems there is some problem with location? I chmod the dat file to 777 already, below is the commands I am running:

```
>>> df = sqlContext.read.text("/home/rx52019/data/airports-extended.dat")
17/08/01 15:29:10 INFO text.TextRelation: Listing hdfs://dev-icg/home/rx52019/data/airports-extended.dat on driver
>>> df.printSchema
<bound method DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[value: string]>
>>>
```

if I run df.show(10), I will get:

```
>>> df.show(10)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_8 stored as values in memory (estimated size 286.5 KB, free 1819.7 KB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_8_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.0 KB, free 1843.7 KB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_8_piece0 in memory on 10.49.31.80:44407 (size: 24.0 KB, free: 529.9 MB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 8 from showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9 stored as values in memory (estimated size 272.7 KB, free 2.1 MB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_9_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 24.0 KB, free 2.1 MB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_9_piece0 in memory on 10.49.31.80:44407 (size: 24.0 KB, free: 529.8 MB)
17/08/01 15:31:34 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 9 from showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 257, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, truncate))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p0.11/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o196.showString.
: java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out by upload the file to hdfs instead of keeping it as linux file

```
hadoop fs -put /home/rx52019/data/airports-extended.dat hdfs://dev/user/spark/
```

and then I changed the loading code to:

```
df = sqlContext.read.text("hdfs://dev/user/spark/airports-extended.dat")
```

df.show(10) is working as expected.